# jQuery slide hide and show same button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this simple jquery slide that I want to have only one button. If the div is being shown, the show button will become a hide button. And if the div is hidden, the hide button will become a show button.

Currently, mine has a separate show and hide buttons. I don't know how to merge this buttons into one. I hope someone here can help me. :(

```
    <script type="text/javascript" 
    src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" 
    src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

     $(document).ready(function() {

       $("#hide").click(function(){
          $(".target").hide( "slide", 
                      { direction: "up"  }, 500 );
       });

       $("#show").click(function(){
          $(".target").show( "slide", 
                       {direction: "up" }, 500 );
       });

    });
    </script>
    <style>

      div{ width:100%; 
             height:100px; 
             background: #000; 
             color: #fff; 
         }
   </style>
 </head>

 <div class="target" style="display:none;">
 My Bag Items
 <button id="hide">Hide My Bag</button>
 </div>
 <button id="show">My Bag</button>
```

Comment: Ooops. never mind I already figured it out. Thanks! :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$("#toggle").click(function(){
    var $target = $('.target'),
        $toggle = $(this);

    $target.slideToggle( 500, function () {
        $toggle.text(($target.is(':visible') ? 'Hide' : 'Show') + ' My Bag');
    });
});
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/qmK26/

Comment: Wow thanks for this. I never thought there are so many ways to implement it. :D

Comment: Btw what if I'm using an icon instead of a text?

Comment: Same principal: `$toggle.html('<img src="' + ($target.is(':visible') ? 'img1.png' : 'img2.png') + '" />');` where `$toggle` would need to be a container that can hold an image. You could also make it an image and just swap the source: `$toggle.attr('src', (($target.is(':visible') ? 'img1.png' : 'img2.png'));`

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Your answer is really helpful! :D

Answer (score 1):

New markup -

```
<div class="target">My Bag Items</div>
<button id="togButton">Hide</button>
```

jQuery

```
$('#togButton').click(function() {
    $('.target').slideToggle(500);
    if( $(this).text() == 'Hide' ) {
        $(this).text('Show');
    } else {
        $(this).text('Hide');
    }
});
```

Comment: FYI Jay it's a good habit to cache `$(this)` as `var $this = $(this);` to avoid redundant lookups and DOM traversal. Any time you find yourself doing `$('someSelector')` more than once in a function, cache it. Cheers~

Comment: Yep - I am aware of that @AlienWebguy. Thanks for the reminder.

Comment: How about if I replace the text with an image, what is the correct syntax? Is this correct? $this.image('img URL') ? O__O