# Logic for showing elements and hiding them on body click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some piece of code. 
This code on button click open menu.
When i click on button again, menu is hidden (i remove .`show` class, show class has `display:block` rule, so i toggle visibility of this item by clicking on button).
In next line, i have event, which check what element is clicked. If i "click" outside" of menu, menu become hidden, beacuse i remove `.show` class.

And now i have a problem, it looks like first part of code dont work anymore (button.on('click')) - i mean, work, but second part of code is also executed, and this logic is now broken.

Have you got any idea for workaround?
Thanks

```
        var menu = $('.main-menu');
        var button = $('.burger');
        button.on('click',function() {
            if (menu.hasClass('show')) {
                menu.removeClass('show');
                $(this).removeClass('opened');
            } else {
                menu.addClass('show');
                $(this).addClass('opened');
            }
        });
        $(document).bind( "mouseup touchend", function(e){
            var container = menu;
            if (!container.is(e.target)
                && container.has(e.target).length === 0) {
                container.removeClass('show');
                button.removeClass('opened');
            }

        });
```

Comment: Check these answers (http://stackoverflow.com/a/23685834/6812815)(http://stackoverflow.com/a/23685834/6812815) and (http://stackoverflow.com/a/13145711/6812815)(http://stackoverflow.com/a/13145711/6812815). Maybe it can help you.

Answer (score 0):

maybe use jQuery `toggle()` method ? For example:

```
button.on('click',function() {
  menu.toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind an outer click event only when the button click event has been triggered, and remove the outer click event when the outer click event has been triggered:

```
var menu = $('.main-menu');
var button = $('.burger');
button.on('click',function() {
    if (menu.hasClass('show')) {
        menu.removeClass('show');
        $(this).removeClass('opened');
    } else {
        menu.addClass('show');
        $(this).addClass('opened');
    }
    var butbindfunc = function(e){
        var container = menu;
        container.removeClass('show');
        button.removeClass('opened');
        $(this).unbind("mouseup touchend", butbindfunc);
    };
    $(document).not(button).bind( "mouseup touchend", butbindfunc);
});
```

Note, that I have removed your condition in the document binding callback, and simple excluded it from the select set.

Comment: Thank you for comment, but when i open menu,i can't close it again when i click button second time.